# error: package com.google.common.collect does not exist

Tags: build.gradle, corda

I've tried looking at answers to similar questions and I followed their instructions, but I'm still getting in the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a missing dependency problem. Add Guava to your dependencies.

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '29.0-jre'
```

Add the above line in the dependencies section of your `build.gradle` in the `flow` module (and contract as well if you are using the dependencies in `contract` module).

Comment: A problem occurred evaluating project ':workflows'.
> Supplied String module notation 'com.template' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.
This is what I got after adding that line.

Comment: It's probably an indentation problem.